# change selection background of listview

Tags: android

in Android,

I have list that I fill using the following code

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    // Change icon based on name
    String s = values[position];

    System.out.println(s);

    if (s.equals("xxxxxxxx")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
    } else if (s.equals("yyyyyyyyyy")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
    } else if (s.equals("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.three);
    }

    // to change the background color


    return rowView;
}
```

how to change the selection color instead of orange , in the layout I use the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#DFE1E5">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/one" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20dp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

to solve that I did that

first add color xml to drwable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<resources> <color name="selection_color">#0587F4</color> 
</resources>
```

secondly I added XML to drwable to handle the selection

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item 
        android:drawable="@color/selection_color"

        android:state_selected="true"/>
   <!--  <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selection_bg" android:state_pressed="true"/>
--> 
</selector>
```

the first problem is that it raaise error regardign "@color/selection_color"

any idea to achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a XML of Selector and save it in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selection_bg" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selection_bg" android:state_pressed="true"/>
</selector>
```

Then add the following code in getView method of the Adapter class

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    // Change icon based on name
    String s = values[position];

    System.out.println(s);

    if (s.equals("xxxxxxxxxxx")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
    } else if (s.equals("yyyyyyyy")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
    } else if (s.equals("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.three);
    }

    // to change the background color
rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.alternate_list_color1);


    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: @drawable/list_selection_bg specify the selection color in R.drawable.alternate_list_color1

Comment: I am confused, I need to change the color of selection  to 0587F4 also the code of the xml give error error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/list_selection_bg'). am sorry I am new to Android

Comment: list_selection_bg is an list selection image in drawable folder,we can also specify it by color in color.xml file

Comment: could u give me example in how to use color.xml to use 0587F4

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="selection_color">#0587F4</color>
    
</resources>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11012/discussion-between-krish-and-amh)

Comment: when say <item 
     android:drawable="@color/selection_color"
      
     android:state_selected="true"/> it raise error that there's no "@color/selection_color"

Comment: rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.alternate_list_color)           where alternate_list_color is name of drawable file described above

Comment: there's problem in this line  android:drawable="@color/selection_color"

Comment: clean and build u r project for generating R.java file

Comment: yes, but the background color, doesn't work, shall I add another field to the selector for it

Comment: the problem in changing the background color from black to another color

Answer (score 0):

in the ListView mention it

android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"

and make list_selector.xml in drawable and paste this code and you can change as per your requirement...

```
<!-- Selected -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_hover" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
<!-- @drawable/tab_focus -->


<!-- Pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_hover" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<!-- @drawable/tab_press -->
```